# Formatting flask-table output with html on python

Tags: python, html, flask-table

Not a very experienced user with python here, just picked up python while staying at home. I was looking into integrating the output of flask-table to a website. The following is my python code that creates a simple table for my website.

```
    from flask_table import Table, Col

    app = Flask(__name__)

    class ItemTable(Table):
        name = Col('Name')
        description = Col('Description')

    Class Item(object):
        def __init__(self, name, description):
            self.name = name
            self.description = description

    items = [dict(name='Name1', description='Description1'),
             dict(name='Name2', description='Description2'),
             dict(name='Name3', description='Description3')]

    table = ItemTable(items)


    @app.route("/")
    def hello():
        return render_template('index.html', tStrToLoad=table.__html__())

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

and my html code that takes tStrToLoad from the python code above to display.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Flask Table</title>
        <style>
            body 
            {
                background-color: #000000;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                font-family:Verdana;
                font-size:16px;
            }
            table, th, td
            {
                border: 1px solid #0088ff;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 3px;
                font-family:Verdana;
                font-size:12px;
                text-align: left;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        a simple test table
        <br/><br/>

        {{ tStrToLoad }}

    </body>
</html>
```

And instead of showing a table with the data, I have the following output in a black background

```
a simple test table

<table> <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Description</th></tr></thead> <tbody> <tr><td>Name1</td><td>Description1</td></tr> <tr><td>Name2</td><td>Description2</td></tr> <tr><td>Name3</td><td>Description3</td></tr> </tbody> </table>
```

Upon further investigating, I did a view page source, this is my actual html code that arises from this.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Flask Table</title>
        <style>
            body 
            {
                background-color: #000000;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                font-family:Verdana;
                font-size:16px;
            }
            table, th, td
            {
                border: 1px solid #0088ff;
                border-collapse: collapse;
                padding: 3px;
                font-family:Verdana;
                font-size:12px;
                text-align: left;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        a simple test table
        <br/><br/>

        &lt;table&gt;
&lt;thead&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;th&gt;Name&lt;/th&gt;&lt;th&gt;Description&lt;/th&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/thead&gt;
&lt;tbody&gt;
&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Name1&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Description1&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Name2&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Description2&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Name3&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Description3&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
&lt;/tbody&gt;
&lt;/table&gt;

    </body>
</html>
```

My question is how do I format it correctly in my python script such that it sends *<* and *>* instead of *& lt;* and *& gt;*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're confident none of the data in the table has un-validated user input then tell Jinja not to escape the html:

```
{{ tStrToLoad | safe }}
```

However you may wish to avoid using Flask-tables, and just pass the items list yourself.  The template code can become more generic if you also pass some headers in a separate list:

```
        headers = ['Name','Description']
        return render_template('index.html',
                               headers = headers,
                               objects = items)
```

Then manually build the table:

```
{% if objects %}
  <table id='result' class='display'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
      {% for header in headers %}
        <th>{{header}}</th>
      {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    {% for object in objects %} 
      <tr>
    {% for k, val in object.items() %}
        <td>{{val}}</td>
      {% endfor %}
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}        
    </tbody>
  </table>
{% endif %}
```

As you can see, this prevents you from having to hard-code any values into the template.

The syntax of this table is also compatible with datatables, so you if you load the CSS and JS files as per the [zero configuration](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html) example then your table becomes prettier and can have a builtin search bar and pagination.  Let me know if you need further direction on how to do this.

Comment: It worked! Exactly what I needed! Thanks man!

There won't be any user input here, so I don't have to sanitize the inputs.

Comment: what do you call this part of the code? {% if objects %}, I want to read up more on this. Thanks!

Comment: @Rascal That's an `if` clause in [Jinja2 templating syntax](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/).

Comment: @Rascal Side note: avoid building complex logic in templates which doesn't strictly need to be done in a template.  When getting started it may be tempting to put things like `{% if somevar %}FOO{% else %}BAR{% endif %}` in a template.  This works untill you wish to obtain `FOO` or `BAR` based on `somevar` elsewhere within the Python program.  Try to keep the templates to *display* logic as much as possible.